# Should I have my site's ASP.NET Identity database separate from my site's "other data" database?

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, database-design, asp.net-identity

I'm creating a website that uses ASP.NET's Identity framework for the authentication/etc.
Should I keep the Identity database separate, and create another database that contains my websites's other information?
I ask because that's all I've experienced (seen in my job) so far, and I want to make sure that it is "best" practice.
My assumption is that there's no need to keep them in separate databases. Is that correct?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not necessary. For simple website, no, there are no advantages to separate both.

But this is a trick question! Do you intend to have more than 1.000.000 user online in the same time?

If yes, you’ll probably would like to have some geo-replication and have separate databases for clients. In this case, have a big fat database only for authentication makes all sense